# How to set content of a FrameLayout just like setContentView

Tags: android, layout

I want something like setContentView but for a FrameLayout inside of my current layout means that I have some bunch of controls in my main_activity layout and one of them is pageHolder which is a FrameLayout. I added an android layout in res/layout which is also FrameLayout called page1 and another one called page 2. I want to change the content of pageHolder to the content of page1 or page2 when application is running.

I do the following code but it gives me error:

```
    FrameLayout pageHolder = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.pageHolder);

    FrameLayout page1 = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.layout.page1);

    pageHolder.removeAllViews();
    pageHolder.addView(page1);
```

and it says page1 is null and I have checked it myself and it was null. Can you help me please?

Comment: So you're tying to put a `FrameLayout` inside another `FrameLayout`?

Comment: exactly, it's possible I tried that but the problem here is that page1 is null means that it is not initialized using the xml file in res/layout

Comment: Is there a view in your layout xml file with `android:id="@+id/page1"`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to me that you should use `LayoutInflater` to inflate that page1 layout. It should look something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
  (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, null);
```

Comment: Instead of context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) you could just write getLayoutInflater()